# Strange unity bug in IOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am suffering from a strange bug in my project. It runs in unity perfectly but when I build it for IOS, it does one thing in particular differently. When a user picks up 8 items, I have an input box display these items and what order they selected them in. This works perfectly in unity but doesn't in IOS. Anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be the case. Below are the two appropriate scripts.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class PickUpItem : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{

    //Go back to older version of clavem, find out what broke. 

    public string DisplaySprite;

    public string DisplayImage;

    public static string ItemChoosenOrder;

    public static int counter;

    public static GameObject InventorySlots;

    public static GameObject[] PlayerItems = new GameObject[8];

    public void Interact(DisplayImage currentDisplay)
    {
        ItemPickUp();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void ItemPickUp()
    {
        InventorySlots = GameObject.Find("Slots");

        counter = 0;

        foreach (Transform slot in InventorySlots.transform)
        {
            if (slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name == "empty_item")
            {
                slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
                    Resources.Load<Sprite>("Inventory Items/" + DisplaySprite);
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            }


            if (counter <= 7)
            {

                counter++;

                if (counter >= 7)
                {

                    {

                        Debug.Log("You have choosen all your items.");

                        foreach (Transform finalslot in InventorySlots.transform)
                        {
                            if (finalslot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name == "empty_item")
                            {
                                finalslot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
                                    Resources.Load<Sprite>("Inventory Items/" + DisplaySprite);
                                Destroy(gameObject);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        //https://hub.packtpub.com/arrays-lists-dictionaries-unity-3d-game-development/

                        if (PlayerItems[7].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name != "empty_item")
                        {
                            PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");


                            ItemChoosenOrder = "1: " + PlayerItems[0].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name + " 2: " + PlayerItems[1].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name
                            + " 3: " + PlayerItems[2].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name + " 4: " + PlayerItems[3].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name
                                + " 5: " + PlayerItems[4].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name + " 6: " + PlayerItems[5].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name
                            + " 7: " + PlayerItems[6].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name + " 8: " + PlayerItems[7].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name;

                            Debug.Log(ItemChoosenOrder);
                            Debug.Log(counter);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Error choosing items");
                        }


                    }


                }


            }


        }

    }
}
```

**saveitemhash**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveItemHash : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField choosenitems;

    public Text playerDisplay;

    public Text InfoText;

    public Button SaveButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (DBManager.email == null)
        {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        playerDisplay.text = "User: " + DBManager.email;
    }

    public void CallAddItems()
    {
        StartCoroutine(AddChoosenItems());
    }

    IEnumerator AddChoosenItems()
    {
        //Using a unity web request to send email and choosen items string to my php scripts which echo a number depending on whether the user is successful or not.
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("email", DBManager.email);
        form.AddField("items", choosenitems.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("https://clavem.000webhostapp.com/userregister.php", form);
        yield return www;
        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {
            Debug.Log("User added successfully.");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            PickUpItem.counter = 0;
            PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User adding failed. Error #" + www.text);
            InfoText.text = www.text;
            PickUpItem.counter = 0;
            PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder = " ";
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        playerDisplay.text = "User: " + DBManager.email;
        if (PickUpItem.counter > 7)
        {
            //Do this for add field in last scene where the passwords are. 
            GameObject.Find("SaveButton").transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            choosenitems.text = PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder;
            GameObject.Find("InputField").transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            //choosenitems.text = PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder;
            //Debug.Log(PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder);
        }
        if (PickUpItem.counter < 7)
        {
            GameObject.Find("SaveButton").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            GameObject.Find("InputField").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void RestartScene()
    {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(3); ;
        PickUpItem.counter = 0;
        PickUpItem.ItemChoosenOrder = " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: You use GameObject.FindByTag and .Find, im not sure it always finds objects in the same order across different operating systems. Perhaps try sort your collections before you use and display them.

Answer (score 0):

Working answer using a List collection and directly linking the order by adding each item to the array corresponding to each inventory slot in the appropriate order.

**PickUpItem Script**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class PickUpItem : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{

    public string DisplaySprite;

    public string DisplayImage;

    public static List<string> itemOrder = new List<string>();

    public static string ItemChoosenOrder;

    public static int counter;

    public static GameObject InventorySlots;

    public static GameObject[] PlayerItems = new GameObject[8];

    public void Interact(DisplayImage currentDisplay)
    {
        ItemPickUp();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void ItemPickUp()
    {
        InventorySlots = GameObject.Find("Slots");

        counter = 0;

        int j;

        foreach (Transform slot in InventorySlots.transform)
        {
            if (slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name == "empty_item")
            {
                slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
                    Resources.Load<Sprite>("Inventory Items/" + DisplaySprite);
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            }


            if (counter <= 7)
            {
                //itemOrder.Add(PlayerItems[counter].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);

                counter++;


                if (counter >= 7)
                {

                    {
                        PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");

                        Debug.Log("You have choosen all your items.");

                        foreach (Transform finalslot in InventorySlots.transform)
                        {
                            if (finalslot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name == "empty_item")
                            {
                                finalslot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
                                    Resources.Load<Sprite>("Inventory Items/" + DisplaySprite);
                                Destroy(gameObject);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item0").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item1").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item2").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item3").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item4").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item5").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item6").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                        itemOrder.Add(GameObject.Find("item7").GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);


                        //https://hub.packtpub.com/arrays-lists-dictionaries-unity-3d-game-development/

                        if (PlayerItems[7].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name != "empty_item")
                        {

                            PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");

                            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                            {
                                Debug.LogFormat("Item[{0}] = {1}", j, itemOrder[j]);
                            }

                            ItemChoosenOrder = "1: " + itemOrder[0] + " 2: " + itemOrder[1]
                            + " 3: " + itemOrder[2] + " 4: " + itemOrder[3]
                                + " 5: " + itemOrder[4] + " 6: " + itemOrder[5]
                            + " 7: " + itemOrder[6] + " 8: " + itemOrder[7];

                            Debug.Log(ItemChoosenOrder);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Error choosing items");
                        }


                    }


                }


            }


        }

    }

}
```